Dafny method does not verify
I have a method that returns the lowest index of the first bad neighbour or -1 if there are none.
If a neighbouring pair of elements have a negative sum then the right neighbour is said to be bad. For example, the arrays [0,-1], [-1,0] and [0,0,-1] each has a negative-sum pair that wraps-around, so the neighbour on the right, which is index 0, is the bad neighbour. The array [-1,0,1] has a negative-sum pair at indexes 0,1 so index 1 is the bad neighbour as it is on the right.
Currently I'm getting assertion might not hold error on v == 0 in the validator. I'm not sure how to make the postcondition stronger to solve this issue.
method BadNbr(a: array<int>) returns (bn: int)
    ensures bn == -1 || (0 <= bn < a.Length && a[(bn - 1 + a.Length) % a.Length] + a[bn] < 0)
{
    bn := -1;

    if a.Length < 2 {
        return bn; // No neighbors to check
    }

    // Loops through the array to find the first bad neighbor
    var i := 0;
    while i < a.Length
        invariant 0 <= i <= a.Length
        invariant bn == -1 || (0 <= bn < a.Length && a[(bn - 1 + a.Length) % a.Length] + a[bn] < 0)
    {
        var leftNeighbor := (i - 1 + a.Length) % a.Length;
        if a[leftNeighbor] + a[i] < 0 {
            bn := i;
            return;
        }
        i := i + 1;
    }
}

// Validator method
method TestBadNbr()
{
    var arr := new int[2];
    arr[0], arr[1] := 0, -1;
    var v: int := BadNbr(arr);
    assert v == 0;

    // Further testing todo
}


Using predicates or other functions are critical to get Dafny to recognize that certain facts are true. Secondly, use implication, ==>, to create conditions which better define the intended specification.
Once you have done that then can get Dafny to verify facts about data, however, it still needs some assistance in the form of assertions to trigger which conditions the data matches.
    predicate IsBadNeighbor(a: array<int>, i: int)
        reads a
        requires 0 <= i < a.Length
    {
        a[(i - 1 + a.Length) % a.Length] + a[i] < 0
    }

    predicate IsSmallestBadNeighbor(a: array<int>, i: int)
        reads a
        requires 0 <= i < a.Length
    {
        IsBadNeighbor(a, i) && (forall j :: 0 <= j < a.Length && i != j ==> (IsBadNeighbor(a, j) ==> i < j))
    }

    method BadNbr(a: array<int>) returns (bn: int)
    ensures -1 <= bn < a.Length
    ensures (a.Length < 2 || forall i :: 0 <= i < a.Length ==> !IsBadNeighbor(a, i)) ==> bn == -1
    ensures (a.Length >=2 && exists i :: 0 <= i < a.Length && IsBadNeighbor(a, i)) ==> bn > -1
    ensures bn > -1 ==> IsSmallestBadNeighbor(a, bn)
{
    bn := -1;

    if a.Length < 2 {
        return bn; // No neighbors to check
    }

    var i := 0;
    while i < a.Length
        invariant 0 <= i <= a.Length
        invariant forall j :: 0 <= j < i ==> !IsBadNeighbor(a, j)
    {
        if IsBadNeighbor(a, i) {
            bn := i;
            return bn;
        }
        i := i + 1;
    }
}

// Validator method
method TestBadNbr()
{
    var arr := new int[2];
    arr[0], arr[1] := 0, -1;
    var v: int := BadNbr(arr);
    assert IsBadNeighbor(arr, 0);
    // assert IsBadNeighbor(arr, 1);
    // assert v != -1;
    assert v == 0;
}

